# Clustering a web server

Tags: linux, web-server, cluster, opensuse

With 4 servers with OpenSuse is it possible to cluster them all together to run websites?
What is involved in clustering and is anything special needed to cluster the machines together so they work as one? Do you need a special OS?

Answer (score 0):

Why both, load-balance them instead, this will be far easier to setup and maintain for all but a few edge-cases. Make sure you define an appropriate service-up trigger/test though.

Comment: Is it more ideal to load balance? HAProxy -> Web Server 2 and 3 -> MySQL Backend?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to use HAProxy to listen upfront and then pass the http request to upstream web servers. Then you have a dedicated mysql server.
You can use rysnc or unison to keep the data synchronized between the web servers.

Comment: Yea, get the HAProxy  and LB just wondering how you could do it via clustering. Never clustered boxes together before and just wondering if you need a customized OS to connect them together and if clustering would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

if your app's are scalable, then use nginx as balancer : http://wiki.nginx.org/LoadBalanceExample

Comment: Yea, get the nginx and LB just wondering how you could do it via clustering. Never clustered boxes together before and just wondering if you need a customized OS to connect them together and if clustering would be much better.